# BundleConfig output files are mssing in my .net core app project?

Tags: asp.net-core, bundle, devextreme

I am using Devextreme reports. I have followed this tutorial : https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/401763/web-reporting/asp-net-core-reporting/end-user-report-designer/quick-start/add-an-end-user-report-designer-to-an-aspnet-core-application

But the issue is when i run this project on browser all files that come from the bundle are missing .

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/thirdparty.bundle.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.css",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
      "node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.common.css",
      "node_modules/devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": false,
      "adjustRelativePaths": false
    }
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/viewer.part.bundle.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/@devexpress/analytics-core/dist/css/dx-analytics.common.css",
      "node_modules/@devexpress/analytics-core/dist/css/dx-analytics.light.css",
      "node_modules/devexpress-reporting/dist/css/dx-webdocumentviewer.css"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": false,
      "adjustRelativePaths": false
    }
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/designer.part.bundle.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/@devexpress/analytics-core/dist/css/dx-querybuilder.css",
      "node_modules/devexpress-reporting/dist/css/dx-reportdesigner.css"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": false,
      "adjustRelativePaths": false
    }
  },

  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/thirdparty.bundle.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.js",
      "node_modules/knockout/build/output/knockout-latest.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr.js",
      "node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr/event.js",
      "node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr/supplemental.js",
      "node_modules/cldrjs/dist/cldr/unresolved.js",
      "node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize.js",
      "node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize/message.js",
      "node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize/number.js",
      "node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize/currency.js",
      "node_modules/globalize/dist/globalize/date.js",
      "node_modules/devextreme/dist/js/dx.all.js",

      "node_modules/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/ace.js",
      "node_modules/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/ext-language_tools.js",
      "node_modules/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/theme-dreamweaver.js",
      "node_modules/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/theme-ambiance.js",
      "node_modules/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/snippets/text.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/viewer.part.bundle.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "node_modules/@devexpress/analytics-core/dist/js/dx-analytics-core.min.js",
      "node_modules/devexpress-reporting/dist/js/dx-webdocumentviewer.min.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  },


  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/designer.part.bundle.js",
    "inputFiles": [

      "node_modules/@devexpress/analytics-core/dist/js/dx-querybuilder.min.js",
      "node_modules/devexpress-reporting/dist/js/dx-reportdesigner.min.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

Startup.cs

```
using DevExpress.AspNetCore;
using DevExpress.AspNetCore.Reporting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication8
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDevExpressControls();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.ConfigureReportingServices(configurator =>
            {
                configurator.ConfigureWebDocumentViewer(viewerConfigurator =>
                {
                    viewerConfigurator.UseCachedReportSourceBuilder();
                });

            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseDevExpressControls();
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Packages

```
    <PackageReference Include="BuildBundlerMinifier" Version="3.2.449" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.AspNetCore.Reporting" Version="20.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build" Version="2.1.113" />
```

Comment: did you ever find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been bumping into this the past couple days. I installed the NuGet Minified Bundler package but it was only after going to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier downloading and installing that did the the Visual Studio bundler begin working.

GL